Intext citations are not numbered correctly in Texstudio with Miktex, windows 11
I am writing a scientific document in Texstudio and Miktex in Windows 11 X64. The only problem that I have is that, when I compile my document, the references do not appear with the correct order. What I mean is that my citation style is [1] [2] [3]... and so on and the numbering is something like [14] [5] [9] in the text.
Any clues on how to solve this issue?
I thank you in advance,
Best regards,

Note that TeXStudio and MikTeX are not relevant to this. Your code is. I'm assuming you are using bibtex or simular. Then you currently have your bibliography listed presumable by last name as that is the standard. You instead want to have ir by order of appearence (super annoying to the reader BTW), thus you need a bibtex style that supports that. Perhaps yuo should start by describing your document instead so we know what exactly you are doing, which packages you are using, which bibtex style?

The standard unsorted style is called unsrt, but you might need another one of you're using natbib hence why we always want information about your document.

I'd add that knowing which operating system you employ (here: Windows 11) is also irrelevant to solving the issue at hand.
